# Which print driver do I deploy? What is a print driver capable of?

Tags: windows-7, hp, printing, drivers

My organization recently purchased a [HP DesignJet T3500](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/large-format-printers/designjet-printers/t3500.html) printer with the [HP Designjet PostScript/PDF Upgrade Kit](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/oas/product-detail.html?oid=5378157). HP offers 3 specific drivers in [2 packages](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=6988389&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4062). Which driver do I use?

When I run the `Add Printer` wizard and I select `Have Disk`, I get the following options:

- The [HP-GL/2 Driver](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=6988389&swItemId=pl_134040_2&swEnvOid=4062) Package contains two drivers

  - "HP Designjet T3500 HPGL2"
  - "HP Designjet T3500**ps** HPGL2"
- The [PostScript Driver](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=6988389&swItemId=pl_134198_2&swEnvOid=4062) Package contains only the PostScript driver.

  - "HP Designjet T3500 PS3"

My understanding is HP-GL/2 printing language is used for plotters (it fits our intentions as AutoCAD users) and that PostScript is for high levels of control and detailed publishing.

My questions revolve around the `HP Designjet T3500ps HPGL2` driver. It gives me the impression that this driver is capable of using multiple print languages.

### My immediate options/questions are:

- Which driver do I install in the client machines?

  - Do I install both the HPGL2 and PS3 drivers with the instruction to users that HPGL2 is for CAD and PS3 is for PDFs/Documents?

#### OR

- Do I install only the mysterious "HP Designjet T3500**ps** HPGL2"?

### Why? :

- What is the difference between the `HP Designjet T3500ps HPGL2` and `HP Designjet T3500 HPGL2` drivers?
- Are Window's print drivers capable of using multiple description languages for output?

  - If so, how could such a driver distinguish the type of content it is printing?  Does it, for example, send this `.docx` to the PostScript interpreter and this `.dwg` to the HPGL2 interpreter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question best suited to be answered by the vendor, which is the quickest, most efficient path to getting a correct answer.

Comment: @joeqwerty I thought it was similar enough to [What printer driver should I use?](http://serverfault.com/questions/125514/what-printer-driver-should-i-use) that it merited being asked. In addition if I do get an answer from the vendor I believe that knowledge, and the reasoning behind it should be shared and easily available on the web, hence the great Q&A/Wiki StackExchange network.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that the [HP Designjet T3500ps HPGL2 driver is intended for printers with the optional accessory `C0C66A Designjet PostScript/PDF Upgrade Kit` installed](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA5-0479ENW.pdf).  As I recall, it just adds functionality, so it will work just fine for a Designjet T3500 without that accessory as well.

Answer (score 1):

We have (3) HPT3500 since February 2015.  We set each one up with (2) sets of drivers.  One for CAD/GIS files using the HPGL2 driver and the second with just the Adobe (PS) Post Script drivers for printing from "PDF's".  The HP universal multi-language driver was discouraged by our vendor.